# grunt.js task, upload via ssh using vpn connection

Tags: vpn, gruntjs

If there is any chance to upload files via grunt.js but using VPN connection?
can't run VPN connection all the time, so process should look like this:

1. connect to VPN, (PPTP)
2. connect to server via SSH, upload all assets,
3. disconnect from SSH,
4. disconnect from VPN

I was trying to find any VPN related grunt.js tasks, but couldn't find anything. all boxes are mac os/linux based, so the only way which i can see is to have simple wrapper script to connect manually to VPN, run grunt task and disconnect.

any better solutions?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will find any grunt-tasks that cover that.
Grunt is a Task-Runner, just like make, rake, ant, whatever. The difference is that Grunt is specifically designed for building javascript-applications. Thats what the grunt-tasks are for - you just have to configure them in your gruntfile. No more telling the System *what* to do, just *how* to do it.

Your Problem has nothing to do with building or compiling a javascript application. Thats why I do not believe there is (or even should be) a task that suits your needs.

As a solution I suggest using a CI like Jenkins, for example. Jenkins would fetch our project, test it (using grunt), build it (using grunt) and than deploy it (using VPN / SSH). Thats what Jenkins is for (although I do not know if Jenkins can create a VPN-Tunnel, but that is a different question).

Comment: current setup is with jenkins, so it's already there. the problem is that I can't have persistent VPN connection. Sending files via SSH is a "task" - connection to VPN it's similar type of task - from my point of view... anyway... will work on simple bash scripts to solve it.